# Confusion with explicit constructor invocation

Tags: java

In the code that I have provided the overloaded constructor with argument which makes a call to the no-args constructor, which inturn should call the constructor of the object class in this case. So how does using the this() keyword execute the program correctly but not a direct call to the constructor.

```
public class S {

    S() {
        System.out.println("S()");
    }

    S(int i) {

        this();
        S();// The method S is undefined for type S
        System.out.println("S(int i)");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        S obj1 = new S();
        System.out.println("----------");
        S obj2 = new S(10);
        System.out.println("----------");

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't _call_ a constructor.

Comment: this() is referring to the constructor

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined. To invoke another constructor, you use `this()`.

Comment: Constructor is not just another method. It has its own rules.

Answer (score 5):

Syntactically, `S()` is a method invocation, but you do not have a method called `S`.

`this();` is special syntax for using another constructor in the same class.

To illustrate this point, I added:

```
void S() {
  System.out.println("Method S()");
}
```

It now compiles, and the output is:

```
S()
----------
S()
Method S()
S(int i)
----------
```

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is defined to initialize (construct) objects, therefore you can't call it.

```
S s = new S();//Correct
S(); //Incorrect, you are calling a method not a constructor.
new S();//Correct
```

- `this()` is used to to pass arguments to constructor of the same class.
- `super()` is used to pass arguments to parent constructor.

This is called *explicit* constructor invocation.

Note that when invoking a constructor from another constructor, it must be the first statement of the constructor else it won't compile.

Comment: Is super() the first statement of all the constructor?

Comment: You are not forced to call super in all constructor, however if you does, it have to be the first statement else it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

How to invoke other constructors of the same class is defined by T[he Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf), section 8.8.7.1 Explicit Constructor Invocations:

> • Alternate constructor invocations begin with the keyword this
>   (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments). They are used to
>   invoke an alternate constructor of the same class.
>
> • Superclass constructor invocations begin with either the keyword
>   super (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments) or a Primary
>   expression. They are used to invoke a constructor of the direct
>   superclass.